# Qual é o equivalente ao comando grep no Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell, grep

Em Linux, quando quero filtrar por um termo quando um comando vai gerar lista gigante, eu uso o comando `grep`.

Por exemplo:

```
 ls | grep "termo"
```

Porém, no Windows não existe o comando `grep`.

Qual seria o equivalente de `grep` no Windows, tanto para o Power Shell como para o CMD?

Comment: Powershell: https://superuser.com/a/701011; cmd: https://superuser.com/a/300821

Comment: Você pode utilizar o findstr. Ficaria desta forma: "dir | findstr String"

Comment: Eu tenho uma ideia melhor, **fica só com Linux!!!** :D

Comment: Instala o bash!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## Pode utilizar duas opções no Windows:

#### Utilizando o Command Prompt: [`Findstr`](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb490907.aspx)

Exemplos:

Buscar arquivos que contenham a expressão: **log**:
`dir /B | findstr /R /C:"[log]"`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

onde:

- `dir /B`: Lista os arquivos/diretórios, do diretório corrente.
- `findstr /R /C`: Aceita expressões regulares e procura uma string literal, respectivamente.

Buscar entre o conteúdo do(s) arquivo(s) a expressão: **log**: `findstr log *`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Utilizando o PowerShell: [`Select-String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)

Exemplo:

Buscar arquivos que contenham a expressão: **log**: `Get-ChildItem *log*`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Buscar entre o conteúdo do(s) arquivo(s) a expressão: **log**: `Get-ChildItem | Select-String -Pattern "log"`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual a função do `/C`?

Comment: `/C` é quando há necessidade de realizar a busca por uma string em sua forma literal, exemplo: se deseja buscar pelas palavras: `log ativo`, usa-se o `findstr /C:"log ativo" *`, mas, se precisar buscar pelas palavras: `log ativo`, separadamente, não precisa informar o `/C`: `findstr "log ativo" *`.

Answer (score 10):

Creio que estás procurando pelo `findstr`no cmd

Exemplo:

> C:> dir /B | findstr /R /C:"[mp]"

No PowerShell é o sls:

> PS C:> New-Alias sls Select-String

Answer (score -3):

O comando grep atualmente já funciona no Windows 10, faz o teste, talvez já esteja disponível na sua versão.

Exemplo:

```
cat package.json | grep react-native
```